# Vertica. GROUPING() on current time in HAVING clause in subquery and outer query grouping

Tags: sql, group-by, vertica

I'm trying to execute the following query, but get the error:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, NOW())
  FROM 
    events
  GROUP BY CUBE(
    DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, NOW())
  )
  HAVING GROUPING(
    DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, NOW())
  ) = 0
) AS subqueries GROUP BY 1;
```

*The query looks strange, because it is just [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The real query consists of multiple subqueries under grouping in the outer query and has more complex conditions in the `HAVING` clause.*

> [42803][7182] [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Grouping function arguments need to be group by expressions

But as you can see the `GROUPING()` arguments are the same as `CUBE()` and the `SELECT` clauses.

If the `NOW()` function is replaced by some fixed value, then the query works well:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, '2018-01-01 00:00:00')
  FROM 
    events
  GROUP BY CUBE(
    DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, '2018-01-01 00:00:00')
  )
  HAVING GROUPING(
    DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, '2018-01-01 00:00:00')
  ) = 0
) AS subqueries GROUP BY 1;
-- ok
```

Does it prohibited to use `NOW()` because it can return different values for different parts of query exection (i.e. when `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` will be actually processed)?
If it's true, then why the following modifications of base query *also make it work, regardless using of `NOW()`*:

Only unmodified subquery beyond the outer query:

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, NOW())
FROM 
  events
GROUP BY CUBE(
  DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, NOW())
)
HAVING GROUPING(
  DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, NOW())
) = 0
-- ok
```

Outer query without GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, NOW())
  FROM 
    events
  GROUP BY CUBE(
    DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, NOW())
  )
  HAVING GROUPING(
    DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, NOW())
  ) = 0
) AS subqueries;
-- ok
```

I can work around the problem by getting current time at the application side, but I just want to understand the issue. Do I miss some fundamental knowledge about SQL or it's a edge case of the Vertica?

Vertica version: 8.1

---

**update 2018-07-04:** the bug is fixed in Vertica 8.1.1-20 (see [this comment](https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/comment/241127/#Comment_241127)).

Comment: Not familiar with vertica but does it support variables? Maybe set `NOW()` as a variable then reference in the `HAVING` clause. I have a hunch the extra parenthesis from the function are throwing off the syntax.

Comment: Thanks, but Vertica does not support variables itself. But it is not a problem: I _can_ provide a timestamp from application side. I just want to understand why it does not work with `NOW()`. Can you explain where are extra parenthesis should be added?

Comment: I don't think you need extra parenthesis, but you could try `(NOW())`. What I'm saying is, it looks like a bug.

Comment: Unfortunately, `(NOW())` is not work too. But it works when it wrapped in the extra subquery (as in the @mauro answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, (select now()))
  FROM 
    events
  GROUP BY CUBE(
    DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, (select now()))
  )
  HAVING GROUPING(
    DATEDIFF('year', event_timestamp, (select now()))
  ) = 0
) AS subqueries GROUP BY 1;
```

NOW() is considered a STABLE function: it will return exactly the same value in subsequent calls within the same transaction.

**Update**

This workaround is fine in most cases, but in some cases it causes the  Vertica's internal error. 
See the relevant discussion at the Vertica forum: https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/239469/

Comment: It works. Thanks! TIL about function [behavior types](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/SQLFunctions.htm). I don't understand yet why `NOW()` it should be wrapped in extra subqueries. So, as @Jacob H said above it looks like a bug.

Comment: Unfortunately, I causes the error in some cases. I updated the answer and attached link to the official Vertica forum.